# How to get content of a file with 'ibm857' encoding and save it to 'IBM00858' encoding

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, mainframe

Recently I am working on a file which is encoded with IBM857 code page and I need to read this file and convert it to 'IBM00858' code page in PowerShell.

I found [Convert XML latin1 to UTF-8 and other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869353/convert-xml-latin1-to-utf-8-and-other-way-around) question but could not be sure about if it works on files which does not extension.

Also found PowerShell has `Get-Content` with encoding with limited code pages and could not be sure whether the
`Get-Content -Encoding Oem` switch is the answer of my question.

Comment: Don't know powershell, but maybe the iconv utility is of help for you.
Take a look at IBM iconv utility https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbcux01/iconvutility.htm

Comment: For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx